# Forward complete http request to another WebAPI (Proxy) .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, proxy

I'm trying to create my own proxy with an asp.net WebApi.
My problem is to forward completely the request as if it has been sent directly from the client to the target server. The problem is that I struggle forwarding the user authentication (credentials) which is made in the frontend with Identity Server 4.

For now it looks like this (still testing)

```
   [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProxyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("TestConnection")]
        public async Task<string> TestConnectionAsync()
        {
            
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var findedCertificate = CertificateHelper.GetCertificate("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            if (findedCertificate is { })
            {
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(findedCertificate);
            }
            var client = new HttpClient(handler) {  Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4) };
           
            var requestmessage2 = HttpContext.Request.ToHttpRequestMessage(); //Convert the message to resend it 
            requestmessage2.RequestUri = new Uri(_baseUri.ToString()+ "DashboardService/TestConnection");
            var test3 = await client.SendAsync(requestmessage2);
            return await test3.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    private Uri _baseUri = new Uri("https://mytargetapi.net:44367");
}
```

The target route is under an [Authorize] attribute.

The original request send a JWT id token

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check with sniffer to see what version of TLS is used.  You probably are using the default 1.0/1.1 and need to use 1.2/1.3.  Add : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer, but what I want to forward is the user credentials. The certificate is working well (If I understood well your answer)

Comment: I do not think this is a proxy issue.  The proxy verifies the certificate.  You need to modify the Role on the Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2.  The server default to making the client a GUEST.  Role allow client credentials to be used on the server.